# Folding and bounce animation with table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, cell

Not sure if anyone has seen this open source :https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell , but I'm trying to accomplish a fold/unfold with a bounce animation with table view cell like the one shown in the above link. Currently I'm changing cell's height and do tableView.beginUpdates() & tableView.endUpdates(). But the results are not very good. I have also tried changing the top constraint of cell's subviews. This does give a better animation but since the cell's height stays the same, this method doesn't make the cell bounce. Anyone has any ideas how this type of animation could be accomplished?

Comment: Try with UIView animation `SpringWithDamping` when changing the top constraint of cell's subviews

Comment: yes, I actually did. Somehow it doesn't change anything really... And what I'm trying to do is change the cell's height so the entire cell and its subviews all have a bounce animation.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the answer is late for this question. Let this be helpful for any new viewers here is a nice animation with fade and bounce.

Add this code to the `tableView willDisplayCell` method of **UITableViewDelegate**

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
 cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, cell.frame.size.height);
 cell.alpha = 0;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.03 * indexPath.row 
usingSpringWithDamping:0.8 initialSpringVelocity:0.1 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        
        cell.alpha = 1;
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        
    } completion:nil];
```

**Swift version**

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: rowHeight)
cell.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.4,
            delay: 0.03 * Double(indexPath.row),
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0.1,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut],
            animations: {

                cell.alpha = 1
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

        })
```

I've added a fade effect also, if not needed remove the alpha portion included in animation.

> The **delay** calculation makes sure each cell at each row has a
> different delay, this makes the animation more viewable at the lower
> portions of the tableview. Setting a higher delay value would make it
> profound at the topmost cells also.
>
> **SpringWithDamping** - essentially a bouncing power. Use value of 1 for no bouncing at
> all and values closer to 0 to increase oscillation.
>
> **SpringVelocity** - Value of 1 corresponds to the total animation
> distance travelled within a second.
>
> **options** - options for animating views. We are using curveEaseInOut to
> cause the animation to begin slowly, accelerate through the middle of
> it's duration, and then slow again before completing.